# android java GET request in new runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to do GET request in new runnable (click button). I've find many totorials in internet (search "variable in new runnable"), but they don't work in my example. I want to do only request wthout handle  response

```
        url = "http://....."

        button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                secThread(url);
            }
        });
    }

     private  void  secThread(String url){
        class MycostomRunnable implements Runnable {
            String url;
            MycostomRunnable(String s ) {url = s;}
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    insertCarinBase(url); // if print "url" it's empty
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
       Thread t = new Thread(new MycostomRunnable(url)); 
       t.start();
   
}
    public void insertCarinBase(String urlserver) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlserver);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }
```

If print variable "url" in "try/catch" block it is empty

Answer (score 0):

You are using twice the same name, "url". Cleanup your code, move class outside of "secThread" function, give more meaningful names, different in different places. Probably compiler is using different variable than you expect.

Comment: What means " give more meaningful names, different in different places " ?

Comment: You are creating two different variables with the same name "url" - change them to two different names, eg. "url" and "restUrl", or "httpUrl", or "serverUrl". Also, don't use variable names like "s", it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution by this way, but i find another way to make request

```
    button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           
                url = ("....");

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // do any thing                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        result_text.setText("ERROR");
                    }
                });
                // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
```

Comment: For requests in Android, please take a look at: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ - it's most popular way to do REST calls.